# How can I scale down a mesh in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mesh that I want to scale down (shrink) in three.js.
I've tried the following code with no hope:

Can anyone advise please?

```
drawMesh(vAngles, hAngles, intensities) {

    let vLines = this.getVerticalDistribution(vAngles, hAngles, intensities);
    let hLines = this.getHorizontalDistribution(vAngles, hAngles, intensities);

    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh();

    mesh.add(...vLines);
    mesh.add(...hLines);

    mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
    mesh.scale.set(0.25,0.25, 0.25);
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: Also the rotation is not working, the vLines and hLines are Lines arrays.

Comment: For the record I use Three.js revision 71 and I have no errors or warnings. It is just the scale is not applied ??

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? I'm afraid I'm not able to reproduce. Modulating `Object3D.scale` should definitely work. BTW: It's not necessary to set `mesh.matrixAutoUpdate` to `true`. This is already the default value.

Comment: I've updated the live example, please check again.

Comment: You have to share the new link when you save a fiddle.

Comment: Here you are [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jq6ovz3m/3/)

Comment: When sharing a fiddle, the idea is to share a runnable live example which does not produce a black screen. I've adjust the camera parameters so you can actually see both lines. Scaling works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/p13azmqk/1/ BTW: Use `THREE.Group` if your lines need a common parent node. Adding a mesh with no geometry to the scene is no good approach.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Fiddle I don't use it regularly. I've adjusted the code again and it works fine on fiddle as I guess it uses Three.js Version 105. Can you try please version71.
Here is the new Link https://jsfiddle.net/nsw0ujrg/2/

Comment: This fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/2xuqypon/) uses R71 and scaling works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I set the scale value to 0.05 the Mesh get scaled down, so I think the units used needed to match the scale ratio.